# trying to download a .msi file abc mouse academy for my children to play

Tags: downloads

Is there a way to download apps on ubuntu? I signed up for ABC mouse academy for my children and it's an app that you download to your computer. I tried downloading it and it is in .msi format. I am clueless on what to do next. Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a Windows program. What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: MSI = MicroSoft Installer; ie. a windows application.  Some can be handled by `wine` but specifics may help